# Is valid to use cramer on this linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

$$\begin{cases} 
y + z =-1\\
2x + 3y+5z=-5\\
x+2y+3z=-3 
\end{cases}$$

I got this result using Cramer and Sarrus

X = 0
Y = 0
Z = -1

But I'm not sure is this is valid.

Comment: This is the solution that I got but I dont know if this linear system is able to apply Cramer.

Comment: @Moo I don't really know how to check it :/

Comment: I used sarrus is correct? @Moo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) requires a system $Ax=b$ with a non-singular matrix $A$. However, this is not the case here; the matrix 
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \cr 2 & 3 & 5 \cr 1 & 2 & 3 \end{pmatrix}
$$
has a $1$-dimensional kernel, spanned by $(1,1,-1)^T$.